# If $f(x)\rightarrow a$ and $f'(x)\rightarrow b$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ then $b=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given: $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable; $f(x)\rightarrow a$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$; $f'(x)\rightarrow b$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Show that $b=0$.

*Proof:

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Given $f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\rightarrow b$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that as long as $h$ is within $\delta$ distance away from $0$, $|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-b|<\epsilon$. As $x$ goes to infinity, we have $|b|<\epsilon$.

**Anything wrong with my proof? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If $f(x) \to a$ then $f'(x) \to 0$ ... that is false.  You really do need the extra assumption that $f'(x)$ converges as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Hint: Mean Value Theorem.  Note, we cannot assume that $f'$ is integrable on  bounded intervals.

Comment: To detail a bit more @GEdgar's first comment ("without the assumption that $f'$ has a limit, then one cannot prove $f'\to 0$"): consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x) =\sin(e^x)e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP proof problem ...

> $f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Given $f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\rightarrow b$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$

For all $x$ and for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ ...
Note that $\delta$ may depend on $x$

> such that as long as $h$ is within $\delta$ distance away from $0$,

so  $h$ also depends on $x$

> $|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-b|<\epsilon$. As $x$ goes to infinity, we have $|b|<\epsilon$.

Well, for a fixed $h$, as $x \to \infty$ we would get $|b| \le \epsilon$.  But (as noted) $h$ depends on $x$, so this step does not work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Take limits on the following equation as $x\to\infty$ $$f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\xi)\text{ for some }\xi\in(x, x+1)$$

Comment: I see your point here. This is certainly correct and seems easier, but does my proof look ok?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh do you mind to take a look at my proof? Thank you.

Comment: @2ndaccount: Your proof has a basic flaw. You seem to assume that $f'(x) =b$ and then apply $\epsilon, \delta$ definition on it. The fact that $f'(x) \to b$ can be represented in the following manner : for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N>0$ such that $|f'(x) - b|<\epsilon $ whenever $x>N$. But from here getting to original function $f$ is not easy without mean value theorem or integration.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $b\neq 0$. Then lets assume $b>0$ (case for $b<0$ can be considered in a similar manner).

Then by definitions, for any arbitrary 
$\epsilon, \epsilon'>0, \exists A, A' \in \mathbb{R} \ \mbox{such that}$,
$$|f(x)-a|<\epsilon \ \forall x>A, \\ |f'(x)-b|<\epsilon' \ \forall x>A'$$
Take $B:=\mbox{max}\{A, A'\}$ so both of the above are satisfied whenever $x>B$

Now, in particular, if $\epsilon'<b$, then $\forall x>B, \ f'(x)>c$ for some positive real number $c$.

Do you see the problem with this when combining this with the fact that $\forall x>B, |f(x)-a|<\epsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose that $b\neq0$. Without loss of generality
(replacing $f$ with $-f$ if necessary), assume that $b>0$. Then
there exists $M$ such that $f'(x)>\frac{b}{2}$ whenever $x\geq M$.
For any $x>M$, by mean value theorem, we have 
$$
f(x)-f(M)=f'(\xi)(x-M)\geq\frac{b}{2}(x-M),
$$
where $M<\xi<x$. Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{b}{2}(x-M)=+\infty$.
Therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, which is a contradiction
(here, I assume that your $a$ is a real number).

Answer (score 0):

Your proof unfortunately doesn't work. The problem is that you write:

> For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that as long as
>   $h$ is within $\delta$ distance away from $0$,
>   $|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-b|<\epsilon$.

If you read carefully, you will see that this says that $f'(x) = b$, which is much stronger than the assumption. Even if you tried to remedy this and substitute $b$ with some $b(x)$ that converges to $b$ (well, this $b(x)$ is just $f'(x)$), there is still problem on directly taking limit $x\to \infty$ on that expression. Here is what we do have:

$$(\forall x\in\mathbb R)(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta(x,\epsilon)>0)\ |h|<\delta(x,\epsilon)\implies \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-b(x)\right|<\epsilon.$$

I want to stress out the importance that $\delta$ is dependent on both $x$ and $\epsilon$. What you'd like to do is take expression

$$\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-b(x)\right|<\epsilon\tag{*}$$

and apply $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ on it. But for that, you need to fix some $h$, and the trouble now is that $(*)$ might just fail along the way because $\delta$ depends on $x$ and nobody can guarantee that $|h|$ won't become greater than $\delta$ at some point, which would make $(*)$ break apart.

Esentially, what you would like to do is along the lines of commuting the limits, i.e. you would like to do this:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = 0$$ but unfortunately, you can't do this a priori, you must use some special properties of derivative, like mean value theorems.

Let me demonstrate what I mean. Essentially, we are given some function $F(x,h)$ such that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x,h) = 0,\quad \lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{h\to 0} F(x,h) = b.$$ You can easily check that function $F(x,h) =\frac{b}{hx+1}$ satisfies the above, but $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{h\to 0} F(x,h) \neq \lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x,h)$$ when $b\neq 0$. Of, course, we are ignoring the fact that in your problem there is another special requirement, and that is $(x\mapsto \lim_{h\to 0}F(x,h)) = f'$ for some function $f$, but then again, so does your proof.

---

Here is one cute way to prove the claim.

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ exists, by L'Hôpital's rule$^{[1]}$ we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x).$

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $M$ such that $x>M$ implies $|f(x)-a|<\varepsilon$. Then we have $$\frac{a-\varepsilon}{x}<\frac{f(x)}x<\frac{a+\varepsilon}{x}$$ so $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x = 0$ follows from squeeze theorem.

---

$[1]$ Contrary to the popular belief that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ must be of indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ (along the other usual assumptions), this is not true. It is sufficient that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = \infty$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ doesn't have to exist at all! You can read it in [General proof, Case 2 section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof) of Wikipedia article on L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: To use L'Hospital rule, we need to make sure that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is an indeterminate form $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$. However, it is given that $f(x)\rightarrow a$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Danny Pak-Keung Chan, you are wrong. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule): "In the second case, the hypothesis that $f$ diverges to infinity is not used in the proof (see note at the end of the proof section); thus, while the conditions of the rule are normally stated as above, the second sufficient condition for the rule's procedure to be valid can be more briefly stated as $\lim_{x\to c} | g ( x ) | =\infty$."

Comment: It seems that you do not understand L'Hospital rule. It can only be applied to the indeterminate forms $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ only. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is not an indeterminate form and L'Hospital rule is simply not applicable here.

Comment: @Danny Pak-Keung Chan, to me it seems you do not understand L'Hôpital's rule. I'll again provide you with [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof), please read it this time.

Comment: @Danny Pak-Keung Chan, specifically, you should look at the note at the end of proof for case 2: "Note: In case 2 we did not use the assumption that f(x) diverges to infinity within the proof. This means that if |g(x)| diverges to infinity as x approaches c and both f and g satisfy the hypotheses of L'Hôpital's rule, then no additional assumption is needed about the limit of f(x): It could even be the case that the limit of f(x) does not exist. In this case, L'Hopital's theorem is actually a consequence of Cesàro–Stolz." Would you please retract your downvote now?